# .net 4.0 asynchronous file copy

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have small .net 4.0 application which basically compares file dates, if the files are changed copyes these from location a to location b. While this copy job is done, it displays little UI with progress bar etc.

How to do this file last write time comparision and file copy asynchronously? As im starting to do this right after the app is started, the app ui is loading very slowly and ui is not updated correcty (as my app is waiting file copy etc).

EDIT:
...and I want to update the UI from long running file task, BackgroundWorker has option for this but what about other options?

Comment: Start it in a `Task` or `Thread`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this type of thing:

```
BackGroundWorker worker = new BackGroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += myWorkDelegate; // method, delegate or lambda that does the heavy work
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += myCompletedDelegate; //method delegate or lambda to execute when DoWork has finished

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a Task (e.g. do it in your load method)

```
Task.Run(() => DoHeavyStuf());
```

The method where you can do heavy stuf async (e.g. I/O)

```
private void DoHeavyStuf()
{
   //Heavy work (simulated by thread.sleep)
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
   MessageBox.Show("Heavy stuf completed");
}
```

For .NET 4.0 you could use (credits: Rotem)

```
new Task(DoHeavyStuf).Start();
```

Comment: I think Task.Run() is .net 4.5 feature, im stuck in .net 4.0.

Comment: You can add a library to work with tasks & async/await for .net 4.0. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) Check nuget

Comment: Just use `new Task(Stuff).Start();`, it's in .net 4.0

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Why is that necessarily a problem?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead While in general I'd agree, it has it's merits. Asynchronous I/O requires holding pinned handles for long (because of the necessary native callbacks) which can cause many many issues. Spawning *one* thread for I/O is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to notify UI after the operation completes, you can use this (on .Net 4.0):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Copy file here
            }).ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
                {
                    if (prevTask.Exception != null)
                    {
                        // log/display exception here
                        return;
                    }
                    //display success result here
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

If you want to copy multiple files an notify UI during that process, you can use this:

```
        var currentSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //do some work
                currentSyncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((arg) =>
                {
                    //your UI code here
                }), "your current status");
                //do some work
            });
```